# Using git, how do I go back to first commit then go through the history?

Tags: git

I cloned a project from Github and now I wish to revert it to the first commit, how would I do this?
Also, once I am back to the first commit, how do I go up to the second commit, and then from the second to the third and so on.

Comment: Duplicate over at Stack Overflow: [Git, Revert to a commit by SHA hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/git-revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash)

Comment: @Bobby: Well, in a way it's a dupe, but the specific application in this case of walking through every revision chronologically is a bit different. Not much, though.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: Not really, at least not in my opinion. "Checking out a specific revision" is not *that much* different from "Checking out a specific revision and after that checking out the next revision". Though, knowing about `git log` would help here.

Comment: why would you want to do that?, can you explain what are you trying to do, instead what you want to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check out any revision by giving its SHA1 id:

```
git checkout <SHA1>
```

A helper script called [`git-walk`](http://pastebin.com/eFGFu9RF) has been made for this. Even if you won't use the explicit script, look at the (very simple) code to see what is done.

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from [the answer to What is the opposite of `git diff HEAD^`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557291/1366033):

First, to make your life easier later on, you can setup a local alias to find the initial commit and the child of a particular commit <sup>(Note: this is not always possible because of the way a  [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) works)</sup>

```
git config --local alias.first-sha "!git rev-list --all        | tail -n 1"
git config --local alias.child-sha "!git rev-list HEAD..master | tail -n 1"
```

Then you can checkout the initial commit and step through the code by checking out each child-sha:

```
git checkout $(git first-sha)
git checkout $(git child-sha)
```

If you're new to git, I suggest reading an article I wrote about [Stepping Through Commits](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/06/StepThroughCodeDemo.html) which details more about each of the commands being used

Answer (score -1):

for all files, try

```
git show HEAD
```

for a particular file, try

```
git log -p filename
```